# datetime format in python to append to a filename

Tags: python-3.x

Following is the code that I am using to get the current date & time:

```
import datetime
date_object = datetime.datetime.now()
print(date_object)
```

Output is: 2019-08-20 15:24:46.670533

I need the output in format: 20190820152446 so that I can append it to the filename like abc.txt_20190820152446

I used the following:

```
    date_object = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(date_object)
    stamp=str(date_object.year)+str(date_object.month)
 +str(date_object.day)+str(date_object.hour)+str(date_object.minute)
 +str(date_object.second)
    print(stamp)
```

Output is : 2019-08-20 15:24:46.670533

2019820152446

Is there a better way to do it in python?
I am new to python.Any help is Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.strftime()`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
date_object = datetime.datetime.now()
print(date_object.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")) # -->20190820154309
```